# React, z-index for each array element

Tags: css, reactjs, state, z-index

Not long ago here I recieved answer, how increase each img as member of array. Somehow the same principle don't wokrs for z-index (increaced img should lie on top of the rest), though console displays that z-index changed. Why?                 [image]

```
class Article extends React.Component{  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {showIncreaced: null}

    this.getImgStyle = this.getImgStyle.bind(this);
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
    }

    increase (incId) {
        this.setState({showIncreaced: incId})
    }

  getImgStyle (id) {
    return {
      width: '20vw',
      marginRight: '0.5vw',
      marginLeft: '0.5vw',
      zIndex: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? '10' : '0',
      transform: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : 'scale(1, 1)'
    };
  }

    render(){   
        const TipStyle={                        
                marginBottom: '10px'
        }

    return(                     
        <div style={TipStyle}>                      
          <h2 style={{marginBottom: '1px'}}>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <div>
        {[1,2,3].map((id) => {
            return <img style={this.getImgStyle(id)} src={this.props[`img${id}`]} onMouseOver={this.increase.bind(this, id)} onMouseOut={this.increase} />
        })}                         
          </div>
        </div>                  
); 
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/fbs3m4jL/

Comment: Your code works correctly as can be see by inspecting the HTML. This is some CSS problem, not react problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `position: 'relative',` to the object returned by `getImgStyle` because `z-index` works only when `postion` is set to something else than `static` (its default value). The easiest way is to use `relative` because the element is still part of the document flow.

https://jsfiddle.net/fbs3m4jL/7/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `position` of your image elements are `static` by default.

If you update the image position to say `position:absolute;`, then the `zIndex` values will work as expected. The catch with this is that you need to position the images with left coordinates so that they sit next to each other. Here is an updated version of `getImgStyle` that illustrates the concept:

```
  getImgStyle (id) {
    return {

      position:'absolute', // Set absolute position
      left: `${(id-1) * 100}px`, // Calculate a left coordinate for image

      width: '20vw',
      marginRight: '0.5vw',
      marginLeft: '0.5vw',
      zIndex: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? '10' : '0',
      transform: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : 'scale(1, 1)'
    };
  }
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle if you'd like to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/gpc0tm1k/)